# Are there experiments in artificial life on the emergence of sexual reproduction (analogues)?

Tags: ai.artificial-intel

I'm aware of quite a few experiments on the emergence of replicators in various artificial life areas, e.g. from [cellular automata](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-30479-1_17) to [computer programs](https://doi.org/10.1162/ARTL_a_00234).

Have any similar result been obtained on the emergence of a recombination mechanism that can be argued to be similar to sexual reproduction?

Comment: I do not know exactly about your question but it reminds me of this paper https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~christos/papers/MixabilityTheory-1.pdf. Maybe it can give intuitions.